# How to get listed in cexplorer.io/collection

Tags: nft, blockchain-explorer

Cexplorer shows "NFT Collections" tab for mainnet https://cexplorer.io/collection and preview https://preview.cexplorer.io/collection . How can collection end up listed there? I have minted nft collections on preview testnet but it's not showing up in https://preview.cexplorer.io/collection (there is only one collection listed in preview testnet atm of writing)

How does this work? Do I have to ping cexplorer team to list some policy as a collection?

Thanks for answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collection data are obtained from [jamonbread.io](https://jamonbread.io) - if they list some collection, then is it available on [Cexplorer.io](https://cexplorer.io)

(preview is manual)

Answer (score 1):

> Disclaimer: This is just a best guess how I think it could be done.

Looks like on *preview* there is (currently) only 1 collection that they probably added manually just for testing.

On *mainnet* I would assume that they take the data directly from the blockchain or maybe from an API like the [opencnft.io API](https://developers.opencnft.io/) or even from [JPG.Store](https://www.jpg.store/).